# Angular Material drag and drop placeholder not showing up correctly when switching between Chip Lists

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material 10 and am trying to enable users to drag and drop chips between two chip lists. One of the chip lists starts empty. In order to enable people to drop anything onto that list, I set the min-height of the child wrapper so that there is somewhere to drop the chip (this is also not ideal, so alternatives to this would be appreciated).

My main issue is that when a user drags the chip over the new list though, the placeholder chip is not placed within the chip list wrapper that Angular creates, but rather as a sibling element to the wrapper. As such, the placeholder just dangles below the empty space of the wrapper. Once the user drops the element, the actual element is placed within the wrapper properly.

Stackblitz showing the issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-twddjn)

Any way to fix it so that the placeholder element actually is placed within the chip list wrapper so that it is rendered correctly?

**app.component.html**

```
<div id='mainView'>

  <h3>Primary One</h3>
  <mat-chip-list 
    cdkDropList
    id='primary-list'
    [cdkDropListData]='primaryOptions'
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['secondary-list']"
    (cdkDropListDropped)='drop($event)'
    class='mat-chip-list-stacked drag-area'
    aria-orientation="vertical">
    <mat-chip 
      *ngFor='let i of primaryOptions'
      cdkDrag
      [removable]="true" 
      style='width: auto;'>
      {{i}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>

  <h3>Secondary List</h3>
  <mat-chip-list 
    cdkDropList
    id='secondary-list'
    [cdkDropListData]='secondaryOptions'
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['primary-list']"
    (cdkDropListDropped)='drop($event)'
    class='mat-chip-list-stacked drag-area'
    aria-orientation="vertical">
    <mat-chip 
      *ngFor='let i of secondaryOptions'
      cdkDrag
      [removable]="true" 
      style='width: auto;'>
      {{i}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>

</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  primaryOptions = [
    'Apple',
    'Carrot',
    'Banana',
  ];
  secondaryOptions = [];
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }    
  }
}
```

**app.component.css**

```
#mainView {
  padding: 10px;
}

:host /deep/ .drag-area .mat-chip-list-wrapper {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 36px;
}

.drag-area {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```